# How to convert with ease, a Newline List into a Column List?

Tags: command-line, bash, passwords

.
Here are the worst 200 passwords of 2020.
https://nordpass.com/most-common-passwords-list/

What is an easy way to convert?

After copying and pasting
200 rows
from above web page ... into file1.txt

Started with this command ...

```
cat file1.txt | tr "\n" "\t" > file2.txt
```

Convert file1.txt -- a Newline List:

```
Position
Password
Number of users
Time to crack it
Times exposed
1.
arrow up green
(2)
123456
2,543,285
Less than a second
23,597,311
2.
arrow up green
(3)
123456789
961,435
Less than a second
7,870,694
3.
(new)
picture1
371,612
3 Hours
11,190
4.
arrow up green
(5)
password
360,467
Less than a second
3,759,315
5.
arrow up green
(6)
12345678
322,187
Less than a second
2,944,615
6.
arrow up green
(17)
111111
230,507
Less than a second
3,124,368
7.
arrow up green
(18)
123123
189,327
Less than a second
2,238,694
8.to...200.
```

Convert above
file1.txt a Newline List to
file2.txt a Column  List:

```
Position              Password    Number of users  Time to crack it     Times exposed   
1.arrow up green(2)   123456      2,543,285        Less than a second   23,597,311  
2.arrow up green(3)   123456789   961,435          Less than a second   7,870,694   
3.(new)               picture1    371,612          3 Hours              11,190  
4.arrow up green(5)   password    360,467          Less than a second   3,759,315   
5.arrow up green(6)   12345678    322,187          Less than a second   2,944,615   
6.arrow up green(17)  111111      230,507          Less than a second   3,124,368   
7.arrow up green(18)  123123      189,327          Less than a second   2,238,694
8.to...200.
```

What is an easy way to convert?

--

Comment: `paste` and `column` will get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

If each line of output was to be composed from exactly 5 lines of input (like the header is), then it would be easy with `<file1 paste - - - - -`. Unfortunately the header takes 5 lines, entries take 6 or 7 lines each. This means you need some logic to build lines of output from the right number of lines of input.

It can be like this:

```
<file1.txt sed '
1 ! {
 N
 /(.*)/ ! N
 s/\n//g
}
N;N;N;N
s/\n/\t/g
'
```

When processing the first line, the condition (`1 !`) is false, so the block (`{…}`) is skipped. The next four lines are appended into the pattern space (`N;N;N;N`) and newlines between all the five lines are converted to tab characters (`s/\n/\t/g`). Finally the pattern space is printed with one trailing newline (because `sed` does this automatically by default). This is the header.

Later the condition (`1 !`) is true, so the block (`{…}`) is executed. Inside the block an extra line (`N`) is appended into the pattern space. If the pattern space does not contain parentheses (`/(.*)/ !`) then yet another line will be appended (`N`). Newlines between the two or three lines are removed (replaced by nothing, `s/\n//g`). At this point we have the first field. The processing continues after the block like it did in case of the header.

You decide if it's an "easy way". :)

The output is in a form of tab-separated columns, quite nice for further parsing. If you want the output to look nice then pipe `sed` to `column -t -s $'\t'` (where `$'\t'` expands to a literal tab character; this syntax works in Bash, not all other shells support it).